# New User of RoR, utilisation of Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a new user of RoR and Ajax and I have a problem loading a page.
With a basic form there is no problem but with Ajax i am unable to send the variable params[:q] to my page.

My working form (but no ajax, and where bobo is similar to my formu_players page below ) :

```
<%= form_tag("/formulaire/bobo", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Nbr participants vers bobo:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

My not working utilisation of ajax :

```
<div id="premier"></div><br/>
<button id="majPremier">maj</button> 

<script>
 $(function() {
     $('#majPremier').click(function() {
        $('#premier').load('formu_players.html').done(alert("popup maj"));
     });
 })
</script>
```

There is my page 'formu_players.html' (.erb) :

```
<%- tab = (1..(params[:q].to_i)).to_a %>
<p>Players :</p><br/>
<%= form_tag("/articles/bubu", method: "post") do %>



<%- tab.each do |player|  %>
  <%= label_tag(:"q#{player}", "Player#{player}: ", :class =>"autocomplete") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:"q#{player}","", :class =>"autocomplete") %>
  <br/>
<%  end %>

<%= hidden_field_tag( :pi , params[:q])%>


 <br/>
<%= submit_tag("Go !") %>
<% end %>
```

I have to use ajax because i want to put this page in a popup. So i wonder how can i transmit a helpful variable to my html.erb page.

Thanks!

Comment: You can send any data you want as the second parameter of jQuery.load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

As in $.load('formu_players', {q: $('#q').val()}).done(...)

Answer (score 0):

[`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) doesn’t assume you want to pass anything. Its second argument defines that:

```javascript
$('#premier')
    .load('formu_players.html', { q: $('#q').val() })
    .done(function () {
        // Note that this has to be done in the callback, not immediately
        alert('popup maj');
    });
```

Comment: Earlier the page was loaded, without the parameter, but she was loaded. Now, nothing happens :/

Comment: @user3450044: Maybe the field name isn’t `q`. What happens if you pass `{ q: document.getElementById('q').value }`? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Nothing happen, yes there an error :  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  31ms]
 (I am learning web programming so i'm not in perfect running with the firefox console ). 
Also,to agree, i should use <%= params[:q] %> in my formu_players.html.erb page to recuperate my variable ?

Comment: Probably. Next step: is `formu_players.html` the right route? What’s actually serving `formu_players.html.erb`?

Comment: I'm sure that it's the right route. formu_players.html.erb, with the variable obtained thanks to the form, will generate an other form with as input as the valour of the variable.
However, as i decided to do that to reuse the code i had written, it's not a problem because i have generate the form with basic jquery.